# AVAudioPlayer initialization & memory management

Tags: ios, memory-management, avaudioplayer

I am trying to figure out something -

Every time I use AVAudioPlayer I need to initialize a new AVAudioPlayer object.

I have 10 **Sentence** objects on a view and I wish to add a "PlaySentence" method to each Sentence object so when the user taps the Sentence the app will play a sound file.

I need this behavior on many views, so I thought  adding the method to the object class so I can simply call -

```
[Sentence playSound];
```

Since AVAudioPlayer is **any way** initialized every time I wish to use it I can not see why this should be more expensive operation.

Am I right / is it a good approch for this need and why?

Thanks

Shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you right, you want your `Sentence` object have a `playSound` method which sets up an `AVAudioPlayer` and plays the sound.

You can definitely do it like that, but be aware that if you have a lot of `Sentence` objects then you will end up creating a lot of `AVAudioPlayer` objects. But you could stop the high water line being too high by releasing it at after the file has finished playing.

Another way you could do this is to have a method on `Sentence` to return the URL of the file to play and then just have a single `AVAudioPlayer` instance in your view controller where you want to play the sounds and set it up each time for the correct file. This would be my personal suggested way of doing it.

Comment: What I don't understand is why does that change as I need to create a new player every time I am changing the sentence? so any way I will have many palyers. BTW I am using ARC so I can not release my player myself.

Comment: If you're changing the sentence then you can still do it like I say with the `Sentence` returning the URL of the file to play / whatever asset it is you're playing. You *can* release the player yourself if using ARC. I do not mean sending the `release` message, but I mean setting the ivar you use for the player to nil, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution for you is to use SimpleAudioEngine from Cocos2D library.

It's easy to use and integrates well. As I know, it uses OpenAL and AVAudioPlayer. It has easy interfaces to control background music, effects and works with mp3, wav, m4a and other formats and codecs.

Using it is very easy:

```
//  it's better to preload all effects during app start so they will play immediately when you call "playEffect" method 
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"sentence.m4a"];
...
//  play effect where you need it
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:soundName];
```

You can find it [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download) inside Cocos2D library. And you can find all useful information about it [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/cocosdenshion%3afaq).